# panToBounds don't adjust zoom

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, zooming

I have following problem, i use `autocomplete` to get coordinates for needed places, i has use before `Autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location` for `map.setCenter()` and have manual make maximum zoom. But i have found, that it given `Autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.viewport`, how i can it understand, it give me 4 X,Y points for corners, so i have put it inside of `map.panToBounds()`. I dont know how, but the map will slide to the right viewport, but with wrong zoom level . Before i start to type in autocomplete, the zoom is on 19, and after i fire action, the map slide to the right location, but position the map Bounds not exactly to autocomplete viewport, it zoom it on the center.

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(my_input,{types:['geocode']});
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()
    {
    my_map.panToBounds(this.getPlace().geometry.viewport);
    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Self fixed, i dont know for what is `map.panToBounds()`, but what i needed was `map.fitBounds()`